# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space for saving into HashMap

Tags: java, performance, recursion, hashmap

JAVA RCP application,  `Windows 7 32bit`, `jdk1.6.0_21`, `Eclipse Indigo`,

We have two revisions of same `XML`. Both are `unmarshalled` to tree. Then revisions are combined to make a superset Tree.

On selecting a tree node in superset `Tree`, we show details of selected node of revision1 in first details table and show details of same node of revision2 in second details table.

To show the details of node (& for other purposes), we are storing respective revision tree node into HashMap (after tree traversal of node after node).

However, when the xml is huge (each revision has more than 50000 nodes), we are running into memory issues(OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space). Max memory of our RCP app is set to 96mb (-Xmx96M).

Current code we are using contains `HashMap` within a `HashMap` (because different 'types' of node exists in tree) with a recursive call:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Node>> refNodeMap;

String nodeId;
```

toCopy is of type Node class object.

```
if (refNodeMap.containsKey(nodeId)) {

    refNodeMap.get(nodeId).put(toCopy.getId(), toCopy);

} else {

    refNodeMap.put(nodeId, new HashMap<Integer, Node>());

    refNodeMap.get(nodeId).put(toCopy.getId(), toCopy);

}
```

Currently trying to replace `HashMap` with a class object, however I will have to use array or `arraylist` in the class for above code scenario which again would cause memory issues.

also looked at `guava` and `FlatMap` from google.

How efficiently can we store tree nodes into collections or any other means so as to retrieve it later for displaying the properties of respective tree node in respective revision details table?
Any recommendations for scalability requirements?

Comment: Are you using DOM to parse the XML? If so, it's a known memory hog. Try using SAX or treat the file as text, not XML.

Comment: What is the purpose of the hashmap?  If you've already got the nodes in a treemap, then why have them in a hashmap as well?

Comment: Why are you restricting the program to 96M of heap in the first place? Basic laptops come with 4GB of memory nowadays.

Comment: WinXP 32-bit should allow you to have a heap up to 1200MB to 1400 MB depending on what else you have running.

Comment: Mobile phones come with 2 GB these days. ;)

Comment: Cannot bump up memory, also nodes are not present in treemap. After JAXB unmarshall, I just get rootnode, thats all. I have to recursively loop and store each node into HashMap